# Calculate Gap In Days Between Instances per Individual (How does one do date math across rows within the same table?)

Tags: sql

**Goal:** identify instance_key where the last instance_date prior occured >30 days, if there are multiple instances with the same instance_date then they all recieve the same value in # of days gap between instance and prior instance

Target output: 5 columns, Individual, Instance_Date, Instance_Key, Instance_Rank, Date_Gap_Days
Date_Gap_Days is the same value for Instance_Keys with same Instance Date (e.g. Instance ABC and EFG both have Instance_Date 2/15/2022 with prior session 1/15/2022 with Date_Gap_Days = 31

**Initial Attempt:** Rank instances per individual and transpose to have instance 1,2,3,4,5 as columns per individual, then do date math across one row rank 2 instance date - rank 1 instance date, and rank 3 instance date - rank 2 instance date etc. Too intensive and does not let me easily aggregate sessions within date_gap buckets, as more than one session can fall into rank 1, rank2 etc.

**Direction:** Thinking there is an easier way to do date math across rows similiar to the above via offset? I'd like to know best practice in doing date math across rows

--starting place for code consideration

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_instance_list AS
SELECT
 a.individual
 a.instance_key,
 a.instance_date
FROM instance_table a
WHERE a.instance_date between '2021-01-01 and '2022-01-01
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;`


`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_instance_rank AS
SELECT
  a.individual
  a.instance_key,
  a.instance_date,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.individual ORDER BY a.instance_date) as instance_rank,
FROM table_instance_list a
ORDER BY 1,4;`
```

Comment: It's always better to give some sample data and expected results, and explain how the output is obtained from the input.  If you have any edge cases, you should include them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.